# Was ist eine self-guided tour auf deutsch?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Ich suche eine Übersetzung für den englischen Begriff "self-guided tour".

Auf einer geführten Tour geht ein Führer mit und erklärt Sachen (z.B. Ausstellungsstücke im Museum), oder man fährt mit dem Tourbus und ein Busfahrer oder Führer erklärt z.B. Sehenswürdigkeiten, an denen man vorbeifährt.

Auf einer self-guided Tour gibt es keinen solchen Führer. Statt dessen kriegen Teilnehmer ein Gerät wie einen Discman. An den Stationen im Museum sind dann Nummern angebracht und man spielt die Audio-Schnipsel zur Station, an der man ist, ab. Die modernere Variante wäre, dass Besucher ihr eigenes Handy benutzen, evtl eine App installieren, und dann an Stationen einen QR-Code scannen, um Informationen auf ihrem Handy zu erhalten.

Ich habe Begriffe wie "Audio-Tour" und [Audio-Guide](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audioguide) gefunden, aber das impliziert eben Audio, obwohl die Information auf dem Handy ja auch Text, Video oder Multimedia sein könnte. "Audio-Tour" ist mir daher zu eng.

Ich suche einen allgemeinen Begriff für eine Führung ohne Führer.

Benutzt man den englischen Begriff "self-guided"? Eine 1:1-Übersetzung, "selbst-geführte Tour"?
"Handy-Tour"? "Eigenständig besichtigen?"

Comment: Suchst du einen Begriff für die handygeführte Tour (das implizieren *obwohl die Information auf dem Handy ja auch Text, Video oder Multimedia sein könnte* und *Handy-Tour*), für Audio- und Handytouren (das implizieren *ein Gerät wie einen Discman* und *Die modernere Variante*) oder für alle Arten von Touren ohne menschlichen Führer (das impliziert *Auf einer self-guided Tour gibt es keinen solchen Führer*)?

Comment: Für alle Arten von Touren ohne menschlichen Führer. Ich habe die Frage entsprechend ergänzt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wenn es ganz allgemein sein soll, finde ich ***selbstgeführte Tour*** (oder *eigengeführte*) nicht schlecht.
2. Wenn alle Arten von elektronischen Führern, nicht aber beispielweise gedruckte (oder erklärende Tafeln) eingeschlossen sein sollen, könnte man an ***elektronisch geführte Tour*** denken.
3. Sofern es sich um ein digitales Medium handelt, gäbe es natürlich auch die ***Tour mit digitalem Guide***/Führer.

---

**Schwierig** finde ich hingegen die Abgrenzung von *eigenständig besichtigen* zur Besichtigung ganz ohne Führer. *Eigenständige Tour* oder sogar *eigenständige Führung* würden meines Erachtens hingegen passen, da sie einerseits das Fehlen eines klassischen Führers implizieren, andererseits das Vorhandensein einer alternativen Führung.

---

Im Übrigen gibt lassen sich aus den oben genannten noch viele Kombinationen mit oder ohne Eingrenzung bilden, von denen du einige schon vorgeschlagen hast:

> - selbstständige(r)/eigenständige(r)/selbstbestimmte(r)
> - Tour/Besichtigung/Rundgang
> - (mit Audioguide/App; mit elektronischem/digitalem Guide/Führer)

oder, unter Berücksichtigung von (3):

> - elektronisch/digital geführte(r) Tour/Rundgang/Besichtigung
> - Audio-/Handy-/App-geführte(r) Tour/Rundgang/Besichtigung

oder

> - Tour/Rundgang/Besichtigung
> - im eigenen Tempo/auf eigene Faust
> - (mit Audioguide/App; mit elektronischem/digitalem Guide/Führer)

Answer (score 1):

Im deutschen Sprachgebrauch hat sich "selbstgeführte Tour" durchgesetzt wie eine Google-Suche belegt. Das ist natürlich die wörtliche Übersetzung aus dem Englischen (Lehnübersetzung), und man kann sich durchaus fragen, ob das wirklich gut klingt oder ob eine andere Formulierung besser wäre. Aber wie bei vielen anderen Angliszmen ist die Frage sinnlos: Die Fakten sind geschaffen.

Answer (score 1):

**Selbstgeleitete Tour**

wäre eine Alternative zu *selbstgeführte*.

Eigentlich ist am Wort "Führung" nichts falsch in so einem Zusammenhang, aber weder "Reiseführer" noch "Schlossführung" wecken die richtigen Assoziationen. Das Wort ist, glaube ich, ***ausgelutscht***.

Als Nomen hat man die Wahl "Leitung" nicht. "Ich biete Stadtleitungen an" geht ja gar nicht. "Ich bin Stadtführer" tönt etwas offiziell und altmodisch. Da sagt man lieber *Guided Tours*.

Aber als Adjektiv kann man "to guide" ganz direkt übersetzen - ist ja nicht "to lead".